# What is the difference between writing to STDOUT and a filehandle opened to "/dev/tty"?

Tags: perl, stdout, tty, filehandle

What are the differences between this two examples?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
my $str = "\x{263a}";


open my $tty, '>:encoding(utf8)', '/dev/tty' or die $!;
say $tty $str;
close $tty;

open $tty, '>:bytes', '/dev/tty' or die $!;
say $tty $str;
close $tty;

# -------------------------------------------------------

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)' or die $!;
say $str;

binmode STDOUT, ':bytes' or die $!;
say $str;
```

Comment: One of them writes to /dev/tty, one of them writes to STDOUT.  Was that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @JB - it's not a trivial distinction for people not terribly familiar with Unix

Comment: @DVK You're right.  I was confused by the Perl orientation of the question when the gist of it was Unix.  Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: @JB - Yay! I'm a source of enlightnment! Now I gotta figure out if I'm fluorescent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that you are writing to two **distinct** and (from Perl's and your program's point of view) **independent** file handles.

- The first one is a file handle opened to a special "device" file on Unixy OS which is "a synonym for the controlling terminal of a process, **if any**" (quote from [this Linux document](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl4_tty.htm)). Please note that while it is commonly thought of as "screen", it doesn't have to be (e.g. that terminal could be linked to a serial port's device file instead); and it may not exist or not be openable.
- The second one is a file handled associated by default with file descriptor #1 for the process.

They may SEEM to be identical at first glance due to the fact that, in a typical situation, a Unix shell will by default associate its file descriptor #1 (and thus one of every process it launches without redirects) with `/dev/tty`.

**The two have nothing in common from Perl point of view**, OTHER than the fact that those two commonly end up associated by default due to the way Unix shells work.

The functional behavior of the two quoted pieces of code will often SEEM identical due to this default, but that is just "by accident".

Among practical differences:

- `/dev/tty` does not necessarily exist on non-Unixy OSs. It's therefore highly un-portable to use tty. Windows equivalent is `CON:` IIRC.
- `STDOUT` of a program can be associated (re-directed) to ANYTHING by whoever called the program. Could be associated to a file, could be a pipe to another process's STDIN.

---

You can CHECK whether your STDOUT is connected to a tty by using the [`-t` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
if ( -t STDOUT ) { say 'STDOUT is connected to a tty' }
```

As another aside, please note that you CAN make sure that your STDOUT writes to `/dev/tty` by explicitly closing the STDOUT filehandle and re-opening it to point to `/dev/tty`:

```
close STDOUT or die $!;
open STDOUT '>:encoding(utf8)', '/dev/tty' or die $!;
```

Comment: Note also that there are plenty of cases where `/dev/tty` cannot be used at all (since there is no controlling terminal) - one common example is a command invoked via ssh as `ssh somehost somecommand` - ssh will, by default, hook up STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR, but not create an actual terminal.

Comment: @bdolan - correct (thus the ", if any" added in the definition I quoted). Or, for a simpler example, on Windows :)

Comment: @JB - thanks for `-t` edit! Just as an aside, IIRC it can not distinguish between `/dev/tty` or any other terminal device.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Portability's a bitch, aint'it?  Then again, IMHO, if someone managed to provide me with an STDOUT connected to a tty other than the process's controlling one, I'd assume he knew what he was doing and let it slide.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what DVK said, you can see the simple difference by saying

```
perl -le 'open $o, ">:encoding(utf8)", "/dev/tty"; print "STDOUT"; print $o "/dev/tty"' > /dev/null
```

The write to `STDOUT` goes to `/dev/null`, but the write to `$o` goes to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

A program launched from an interactive shell normally write standard output to a terminal, which would render `/dev/tty` and `STDOUT` as the same destination. But there are several circumstances where output to `STDOUT` could be written to some other destination.

`STDOUT` may be routed to a separate file:

```
perl someprogram.pl > a/file
perl someprogram.pl >> a/file
```

`STDOUT` may be routed to the input of another program

```
perl someprogram.pl | /usr/bin/mailx -s "Program Output" foo@bar.com
```

Also, the program could be launched from a non-interactive shell, like a cron job or from some other daemon running on your system. The environments for these programs will not have access to a `/dev/tty` device, and `STDOUT` in these programs will be routed somewhere else (or nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

**1. what stdout, stderr, stdin is**? they are **alias** for fd/0, fd/1, fd/2

```
root@192-168-31-33:~# ls -alh /dev/std*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 10 06:35 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 10 06:35 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 10 06:35 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1

root@192-168-31-33:~# echo hello > /proc/self/fd/1
hello
```

**2. what /dev/console is**? /dev/console is pointed to **tty1 or ttyS0**.
[image: tty]

**3.what relationship is between the /dev/std{out, in, err} and tty* devices?** the devices /dev/std{out, in, err} are a wapper of tty* devices.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void print_tty(char* name, FILE * f) {
  printf("%s (fileno %d): ", name, fileno(f));
  if (isatty(fileno(f))) printf("TTY %s\n", ttyname(fileno(f)));
  else                   printf("not a TTY\n");
}
int main(void) {
  print_tty("stdin ", stdin);
  print_tty("stdout", stdout);
  print_tty("stderr", stderr);
}
```

[image]
or, a more simple example:
[image]