# How to redirect apt-file update output

Tags: linux, bash, perl, python-2.7, io-redirection

I want access the output from the command `apt-file update` in a python script.
Unfortunately, I am not able to access the output. My tries:

```
# Does not work:
popen_ret = subprocess.Popen([r'apt-file', 'update']), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = popen_ret.communicate()[0]
print output

# Without the "update" argument, it does work:
popen_ret = subprocess.Popen([r'apt-file'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = popen_ret.communicate()[0]
print output
```

My guess is that the problemis with apt-file itself as, even directly from the console, this creates an empty file:

```
apt-file update > delme.txt
```

Yet

```
apt-file > delme.txt
```

works fine.

Other peopele seem to have had the same problem (but no solution):
[question posed at http://www.linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/apt-file-output-redirection-to-file-945761/)

Comment: what happens if you apt-file update > delme.txt 2>&1 ?

Comment: "I am not able to access the output", did you mean it was print on your console ? If yes, it may be the error output. Try to replace `>` by `2>` or `&>` for both outputs.

Comment: @BigMike: an empty file delme.txt is the result

Comment: @Aracthor: This also gives me an empty file: `apt-file update &> delme.txt`

Comment: `apt-file update 1> tmp` gives an empty file but `apt-file update 2> tmp` gives a part of the output. This is probably related to the fact that apt-file is a perl script.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni: Thanks for the hint. But shouldn't a perl script behave just like any other console program and allow to redirect the output? If things are different for perl scripts, how do I redirect all output from a perl program via the console?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Perl scripts are no different than other scripts.  It is possible that the script's author was careless about mixing output with error messages, but that's a feature of the author, not of Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-file` is a perl script calling another perl script `diffindex-download`.

All the output produce when `apt-file update` is run is generated by `diffindex-download`.

I'm not a perl expert but apparently this script write to `/dev/tty` and not to `stdout`. You can read about the difference here:
[What is the difference between writing to STDOUT and a filehandle opened to "/dev/tty"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667154/what-is-the-difference-between-writing-to-stdout-and-a-filehandle-opened-to-de)

So if you want to redirect the output of this script you should do

```
script -c "apt-file update" output.log
```

Comment: Good find.  Seems like undocumented behavior.

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni: `apt-file update /dev/tty > delme.txt` still gives me an empty file. Typing `tty` at the console returns `/dev/pts/15`. Redirecting this does not work either.

Comment: I've done some modifications in apt-file....  I'will improve my answer but I've to go to work...